# Android: querying MediaStore.Audio.Artists.Albums

Tags: android, media, android-contentprovider

Currently I'm successfully querying MediaStore.Audio.Artists.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI through the normal ContentResolver, and getting the expected results. The docs say there's a nested class MediaStore.Audio.Artists.Albums that's a subdirectory containing every album for each artist, however it doesn't have an equivalent EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI. How can I query it?

Or more generally, given an artist, how do I list each album containing a song by that artist? Currently I'm doing it by exhaustive search through MediaStore.Audio.Media searching for the artist and recording each album in a HashMap, but this seems both wrong and inefficient. Is there a more efficient way that directly uses the ContentProviders?

Answer (score 3):

That's not quite the way you want to do what I think you want to do..  If it is, you can get all albums for an artist -- not the album artist -- by hitting the Media table (Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI) for distinct Media.ALBUM with Media.ARTIST_ID in your where clause.  That will work in any Android version.

However... if you want to work with Album Artists...

Before 2.3.3, the Album Artist MP3 tag was ignored and is not in the Media Store schema.  It's there now -- CyanogenMod has it, for example -- but it is not yet documented.  If you plan to publish your code, you would either need to test for it and work around if it's missing or restrict your code to versions of Android that have it.  Otherwise, you're stuck with the the artist database, which represents each artist on each track, which is probably not what you're after if you're thinking about albums.

Here's the test I have in my code:

```
Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(Albums.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
if ((cur.getColumnIndex("album_artist") == -1) || (cur.getColumnIndex("album_artist_id") == -1))
{
    showartist = false;
}
else
{
    showartist = true;
}
```

You can do a select for distinct ids to get a list of Album artists with something like this:

```
cur = getContentResolver().query(Albums.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, new String[]{"distinct album_artist_id", "album_artist"}, null, null, "album_artist collate nocase");
```

Note that, because the columns aren't documented and the constants aren't available, you'll have to make up your own constants or hard-code the strings.  You can probably figure out the rest from there.

Comment: Thanks, you were right the first time, I want all ALBUMs containing at least one song by ARTIST, not the album artist tag, which I know is separate. Also, ideally I'd like to get back a cursor that I can pass to a ListView, so it needs to contain an _ID, which rules out the use of distinct.

I'm also concerned about using DISTINCT since it assumes the content provider is backed by an SQL database which may not be the case in future (it's a bit "hacky"). I would like to know how MediaStore.Audio.Artists.Albums is queried, I assume that's possible otherwise why would it be in the docs?

Comment: There is a Media.ALBUM_ID available to apply to the first half of my answer.  I wouldn't worry about using 'distinct'.  SQLite isn't going away anytime soon.

Answer (score 0):

The Uri:
MediaStore.Audio.Artists.Albums.getContentUri("external", );
worked for me.